# Внести изменения в ячейку таблицы, QTableView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

Есть интерфейс, в котором таблица нарисована как `QTableView`. 
В апи, связанном с программой, есть некоторые данные, которые загружаются и формируют определённое количество колонок, строк и так далее в самой программе.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу внести изменения в ячейки таблицы, потому что "просто покликать", как в случае с таблицей с изначально нарисованными полями и прочим, я не могу, то есть программа просто не даёт мне это сделать.

Спасибо за внимание!

**Upd**:

Вот класс, который формирует таблицу, здесь мне нужна функция, которая позволит вносить изменения в ячейки. (`tasks` загружается из другого класса, там `requests` и так далее):

```
class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tasks = []

    def rowCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self.tasks)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return 7

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            if column == 0:
                return self.tasks[row].title
            elif column == 1:
                return self.tasks[row].start_date.toString()
            elif column == 2:
                return self.tasks[row].end_date.toString()
            elif column == 3:
                return self.tasks[row].man_hours
            elif column == 4:
                return self.tasks[row].task_type
            elif column == 5:
                return self.tasks[row].done
        return None

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=None):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return ["Задача", "Дата начала", "Дата конца", "Отдел", "Количество человек", "Трудоёмкость", "Выполнение"][section]
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста вашу программу.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо переопределить метод `setData`. Попробуйте пример ниже:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, tasks, parent=None):         # +++
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.tasks = tasks                          # +++

    def rowCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self.tasks)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return 7

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            if column == 0:
                return self.tasks[row]#.title
            elif column == 1:
                return self.tasks[row]#.start_date.toString()
            elif column == 2:
                return self.tasks[row]#.end_date.toString()
            elif column == 3:
                return self.tasks[row]#.man_hours
            elif column == 4:
                return self.tasks[row]#.task_type
            elif column == 5:
                return self.tasks[row]#.done
        return None

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=None):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return ["Задача", "Дата начала", "Дата конца", 
                        "Отдел", "Количество человек", "Трудоёмкость", 
                        "Выполнение"][section]
    
    def setData(self, index, tasks, role):       # <--- # +++
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            row    = index.row()
            #column = index.column()
            self.tasks[row] = tasks[row]
            return True
        return False
                        
                
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tasks = ["1a","2a","3a","4a","5a","6a"]   # Начальное заполнение 
        self.model = TableModel(tasks)
        self.table = QTableView()
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()                     
        self.table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)    
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)         
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        btn = QPushButton("Click me")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
        
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(btn, 1, 0)
        
    def btnClicked(self):
        rows = self.model.rowCount()
        for row in range(rows): 
            self.model.setData(self.model.index(row, 0), 
                               ["21a","22a","23a","24a","25a","26a"],   # +++
                               Qt.EditRole)
        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    mw.setGeometry(400, 100, 550, 300) 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

Редактируемые модели должны реализовать `setData()` и `flags()`, чтобы возвращать значение,
содержащее `Qt::ItemIsEditable`.

> bool QAbstractItemModel::`setData`(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole)
>
> Устанавливает для данных роли для элемента с индексом значение.
> В случае успеха возвращает true; в противном случае возвращает false.
>
> Реализация базового класса возвращает false.
> Для редактируемых моделей необходимо заново реализовать эту функцию и data().

> Qt::ItemFlags QAbstractTableModel::`flags`(const QModelIndex &index) const
>
> Переопределения: QAbstractItemModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):         
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tasks = [[['%d - %d' % (i, j), False] for j in range(7)] for i in range(10)]                          # +++

    def rowCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self.tasks)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return 7
        
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=None):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return ["Задача", "Дата начала", "Дата конца", 
                        "Отдел", "Кол-во человек", "Трудоёмкость", 
                        "Выполнение"][section]
    
    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid():
            data, changed = self.tasks[index.row()][index.column()]

            if role in [Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole]:
                return data

    def setData(self, index, value, role):                                     # !!!
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self.tasks[index.row()][index.column()] = [value, True]
            return True
        return False
      
    def flags(self, index):                                                    # !!!
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.model = TableModel() 
        self.table = QTableView()
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()                     
        self.table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)    
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)         
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(750, 300)
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо!
Но дело в том, что мне нужно вносить изменения именно в процессе работы программы, а здесь, насколько я понимаю, задаётся изначальное заполнение.

Comment: @rolkins я обновил свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: @rolkins что не так?